# MYSQL average every minute

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of values in a mysql table at the same minute and i want to select the avg value to show a single value per minute:

```
DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:22:00 54.8611

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:22:00 45.4861

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:22:00 51.7361

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:22:00 83.3333

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:23:00 135.764

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:23:00 134.722

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:23:00 135.764

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:24:00 135.417

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:24:00 135.069

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:24:00 133.681

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:25:00 134.375

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:25:00 134.375

DEBIT   2018-02-15 09:25:00 133.681
```

Output:

```
DEBIT APA RACIRE SCALAT 2018-02-15 09:22:00 88.8611

DEBIT APA RACIRE SCALAT 2018-02-15 09:23:00 148.542

DEBIT APA RACIRE SCALAT 2018-02-15 09:24:00 135.875

DEBIT APA RACIRE SCALAT 2018-02-15 09:25:00 134.611
```

Comment: It would be great if you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

assumin your_date is a datetime column type you could group by  `HOUR(your_date), MINUTE(Your_date)`

```
select DATE(your_date), HOUR(your_date), MINUTE(Your_date), AVG(your_value)
from your_table
GROUP BY DATE(your_date), HOUR(your_date), MINUTE(Your_date)
```

Comment: What i wrote is only an exemple. I have to do a monthly report with the avg per minute

Comment: "assumin your_date is a datetime column type you could group by HOUR(your_date), MINUTE(Your_date)" DATE(), HOUR(), MINUTE() functions also work on char or varchar column(s) if the string format is a parseable MySQL dateformat

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating by an appropriate call to `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y,%m,%d %h,%i'),
    AVG(TEMP) AS avg_temp
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y,%m,%d %h,%i');
```